# Can't execute Python Pandas set_value

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Got a problem with Pandas in Python 3.5

I read local csv using Pandas, the csv contains pure data, no header involved. Then I assigned column name using

```
df= pd.read_csv(filePath, header=None)
df.columns=['XXX', 'XXX'] #for short, totally 11 cols
```

The csv has 11 columns, one of them is string, others are integer.

Then I tried to replace string column by integer value in a loop, cell by cell

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print(i, row['Name'])
    df.set_value(i, 'Name', 123)
```

intrger 123 is an example, not every cell under this column is 123. 
print function works well if I remove set_value, but with

```
df.set_value(i, 'Name', 123)
```

Then error info:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/xxx/test.py", line 20,
>   in 
>       df.set_value(i, 'Name', 233)
>
> File
>   "E:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line
>   1862, in set_value
>       series = self._get_item_cache(col)
>
> File
>   "E:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 1351, in _get_item_cache
>       res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
>
> File
>   "E:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line
>   2334, in _box_item_values
>
> return self._constructor(values.T, columns=items, index=self.index)
>
> AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no
>   attribute 'T'

But if I create a dataframe manually in code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1, 2], columns=['x', 'y'])
df['x'] = 2
df['y'] = 'BBB'
print(df)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.set_value(i, 'y', 233)


print('\n')
print(df)
```

It worked. I am wondering maybe there is something I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you want just to do the following instead of your loop: `df['Name'] = 123`?

Comment: Because not every cell to be 123

Comment: But in your code you are setting 123 to the whole `Name` column - could you clarify what are you going to achieve?

Comment: @MaxU for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.set_value(i, 'y', 233) should update cell row by row. Coz it is executed in a loop

Comment: did you try `df['Name'] = 123`, where `Name` is the column-name, you want to update???

Comment: @MaxU Yes I did. I tried first make entire column to be integer 123, then update cell by row in a loop, but got same errors I posted.

Comment: Can you post a data set where we could reproduce your error? And beside that - what are you going to achieve? It's still not clear why are you using `set_value()` in loop instead of working with vectorized data sets (like columns)? [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Your example works perfectly here, importing from a csv file. There should be no difference in the dataframes if you create them in the code or from a file. It is not a problem from set_value(). At least in pandas 0.18.

Comment: For which value of `i` is the error raised? What is the corresponding row? You can print values of `i` and `row` right after the error. But I agree with @MaxU, if you don't have any specific reason to use `set_value`, it might be better to use `.loc` or `at` if speed is the concern.

Comment: @MaxU Say the particular column is about city. My goal is to replace string city name with city ID, to make the dataframe all numerical. I'll try to use Apply to merge two dataframe instead of using set_value. Thanks for the hints

Comment: @Luis Yea, hard to find where root is..

Comment: @ayhan error raised from first time, when i = 0. Yes, print i and row.

Answer (score 21):

The cause of the original error:

Pandas DataFrame set_value(index, col, value) method will return the posted obscure AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'T' when the dataframe being modified has duplicate column names.

The error can be reproduced using the code above by @Windtalker where the only change made is that the column names are now both 'x' rather than 'x' and 'y'.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1, 2], columns=['x', 'x'])
df['x'] = 2
df['y'] = 'BBB'
print(df)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.set_value(i, 'y', 233)

print('\n')
print(df)
```

Hopefully this helps someone else diagnose the same issue.

Comment: Very difficult to trace this problem back to the duplicated columns. It's actually a bug, I would say. Have you reported it?

Answer (score 0):

well, now when you made it lot clearer, it's easier to answer your question...

assuming your DF looks like this:

```
In [164]: df
Out[164]:
    a   b   c   d   e          city
0   6  55   3  48  11          Kiev
1   5  29  42  95  69        Munich
2  53  79  60  80  89        Berlin
3   6  70  87   6  85      New York
4  97  23  94  43  31         Paris
5  15  17  56  34  77  Zaporizhzhia
6  28  35  58  82  33        Warsaw
7  41  93  60  54  21      Hurghada
8  68  23  80  39  66          Bern
9  15  17  30  26  98          Lviv
```

and you hasve another DF with city-id's:

```
In [165]: cities
Out[165]:
              id
city
Warsaw         6
Kiev           0
New York       3
Hurghada       7
Munich         1
Paris          4
Berlin         2
Zaporizhzhia   5
Lviv           9
Bern           8
```

you can map city to city-id like this:

```
In [168]: df['city_id'] = df['city'].map(cities['id'])

In [169]: df
Out[169]:
    a   b   c   d   e          city  city_id
0   6  55   3  48  11          Kiev        0
1   5  29  42  95  69        Munich        1
2  53  79  60  80  89        Berlin        2
3   6  70  87   6  85      New York        3
4  97  23  94  43  31         Paris        4
5  15  17  56  34  77  Zaporizhzhia        5
6  28  35  58  82  33        Warsaw        6
7  41  93  60  54  21      Hurghada        7
8  68  23  80  39  66          Bern        8
9  15  17  30  26  98          Lviv        9
```

PS when working with Pandas in 95% you don't really need to loop through your DF's in order to achieve your goals